# includes/MysqliDb.php on line 823 error - url shortener ads 1.3_2

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

* @author    Josh Campbell 
 * @author    Alexander V. Butenko 
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html GNU Public License
 * @version   2.0
 **/
class MysqliDb
{
    /**
     * Static instance of self
     *
     * @var MysqliDb
     */
    protected static $_instance;
    /**
     * Table prefix
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $_prefix;
    /**
     * MySQLi instance
     *
     * @var mysqli
     */
    protected $_mysqli;
    /**
     * The SQL query to be prepared and executed
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_query;
    /**
     * The previously executed SQL query
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_lastQuery;
    /**
     * An array that holds where joins
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_join = array(); 
    /**
     * An array that holds where conditions 'fieldname' => 'value'
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_where = array();
    /**
     * Dynamic type list for order by condition value
     */
    protected $_orderBy = array(); 
    /**
     * Dynamic type list for group by condition value
     */
    protected $_groupBy = array(); 
    /**
     * Dynamic array that holds a combination of where condition/table data value types and parameter referances
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_bindParams = array(''); // Create the empty 0 index
    /**
     * Variable which holds an amount of returned rows during get/getOne/select queries
     *
     * @var string
     */ 
    public $count = 0;
    /**
     * Variable which holds last statement error
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_stmtError;

```
/**
 * Database credentials
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $host;
protected $username;
protected $password;
protected $db;
protected $port;

/**
 * Is Subquery object
 *
 */
protected $isSubQuery = false;

/**
 * @param string $host
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $db
 * @param int $port
 */
public function __construct($host = NULL, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $db = NULL, $port = NULL)
{
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->db = $db;
    if($port == NULL)
        $this->port = ini_get ('mysqli.default_port');
    else
        $this->port = $port;

    if ($host == null && $username == null && $db == null) {
        $this->isSubQuery = true;
        return;
    }

    // for subqueries we do not need database connection and redefine root instance
    $this->connect();
    $this->setPrefix();
    self::$_instance = $this;
}

/**
 * A method to connect to the database
 *
 */
public function connect()
{
    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    $this->_mysqli = new mysqli ($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db, $this->port)
        or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');

    $this->_mysqli->set_charset ('utf8');
}
/**
 * A method of returning the static instance to allow access to the
 * instantiated object from within another class.
 * Inheriting this class would require reloading connection info.
 *
 * @uses $db = MySqliDb::getInstance();
 *
 * @return object Returns the current instance.
 */
public static function getInstance()
{
    return self::$_instance;
}

/**
 * Reset states after an execution
 *
 * @return object Returns the current instance.
 */
protected function reset()
{
    $this->_where = array();
    $this->_join = array();
    $this->_orderBy = array();
    $this->_groupBy = array(); 
    $this->_bindParams = array(''); // Create the empty 0 index
    $this->_query = null;
    $this->count = 0;
}

/**
 * Method to set a prefix
 * 
 * @param string $prefix     Contains a tableprefix
 */
public function setPrefix($prefix = '')
{
    self::$_prefix = $prefix;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Pass in a raw query and an array containing the parameters to bind to the prepaird statement.
 *
 * @param string $query      Contains a user-provided query.
 * @param array  $bindParams All variables to bind to the SQL statment.
 * @param bool   $sanitize   If query should be filtered before execution
 *
 * @return array Contains the returned rows from the query.
 */
public function rawQuery ($query, $bindParams = null, $sanitize = true)
{
    $this->_query = $query;
    if ($sanitize)
        $this->_query = filter_var ($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                                FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();

    if (is_array($bindParams) === true) {
        $params = array(''); // Create the empty 0 index
        foreach ($bindParams as $prop => $val) {
            $params[0] .= $this->_determineType($val);
            array_push($params, $bindParams[$prop]);
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->refValues($params));

    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->reset();

    return $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
}

/**
 *
 * @param string $query   Contains a user-provided select query.
 * @param int    $numRows The number of rows total to return.
 *
 * @return array Contains the returned rows from the query.
 */
public function query($query, $numRows = null)
{
    $this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery($numRows);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->reset();

    return $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
}

/**
 * A convenient SELECT * function.
 *
 * @param string  $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
 * @param integer $numRows   The number of rows total to return.
 *
 * @return array Contains the returned rows from the select query.
 */
public function get($tableName, $numRows = null, $columns = '*')
{
    if (empty ($columns))
        $columns = '*';

    $column = is_array($columns) ? implode(', ', $columns) : $columns; 
    $this->_query = "SELECT $column FROM " .self::$_prefix . $tableName;
    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery($numRows);

    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return $this;

    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->reset();

    return $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
}

/**
 * A convenient SELECT * function to get one record.
 *
 * @param string  $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
 *
 * @return array Contains the returned rows from the select query.
 */
public function getOne($tableName, $columns = '*') 
{
    $res = $this->get ($tableName, 1, $columns);

    if (is_object($res))
        return $res;

    if (isset($res[0]))
        return $res[0];

    return null;
}

/**
 *
 * @param <string $tableName The name of the table.
 * @param array $insertData Data containing information for inserting into the DB.
 *
 * @return boolean Boolean indicating whether the insert query was completed succesfully.
 */
public function insert($tableName, $insertData)
{
    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    $this->_query = "INSERT into " .self::$_prefix . $tableName;
    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery(null, $insertData);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->reset();

    return ($stmt->affected_rows > 0 ? $stmt->insert_id : false);
}

/**
 * Update query. Be sure to first call the "where" method.
 *
 * @param string $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
 * @param array  $tableData Array of data to update the desired row.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function update($tableName, $tableData)
{
    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    $this->_query = "UPDATE " . self::$_prefix . $tableName ." SET ";

    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery (null, $tableData);
    $status = $stmt->execute();
    $this->reset();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->count = $stmt->affected_rows;

    return $status;
}

/**
 * Delete query. Call the "where" method first.
 *
 * @param string  $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
 * @param integer $numRows   The number of rows to delete.
 *
 * @return boolean Indicates success. 0 or 1.
 */
public function delete($tableName, $numRows = null)
{
    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    $this->_query = "DELETE FROM " . self::$_prefix . $tableName;

    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery($numRows);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->reset();

    return ($stmt->affected_rows > 0);
}

/**
 * This method allows you to specify multiple (method chaining optional) AND WHERE statements for SQL queries.
 *
 * @uses $MySqliDb->where('id', 7)->where('title', 'MyTitle');
 *
 * @param string $whereProp  The name of the database field.
 * @param mixed  $whereValue The value of the database field.
 *
 * @return MysqliDb
 */
public function where($whereProp, $whereValue = null, $operator = null)
{
    if ($operator)
        $whereValue = Array ($operator => $whereValue);

    $this->_where[] = Array ("AND", $whereValue, $whereProp);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * This method allows you to specify multiple (method chaining optional) OR WHERE statements for SQL queries.
 *
 * @uses $MySqliDb->orWhere('id', 7)->orWhere('title', 'MyTitle');
 *
 * @param string $whereProp  The name of the database field.
 * @param mixed  $whereValue The value of the database field.
 *
 * @return MysqliDb
 */
public function orWhere($whereProp, $whereValue = null, $operator = null)
{
    if ($operator)
        $whereValue = Array ($operator => $whereValue);

    $this->_where[] = Array ("OR", $whereValue, $whereProp);
    return $this;
}
/**
 * This method allows you to concatenate joins for the final SQL statement.
 *
 * @uses $MySqliDb->join('table1', 'field1 <> field2', 'LEFT')
 *
 * @param string $joinTable The name of the table.
 * @param string $joinCondition the condition.
 * @param string $joinType 'LEFT', 'INNER' etc.
 *
 * @return MysqliDb
 */
 public function join($joinTable, $joinCondition, $joinType = '')
 {
    $allowedTypes = array('LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT OUTER', 'RIGHT OUTER');
    $joinType = strtoupper (trim ($joinType));
    $joinTable = filter_var($joinTable, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ($joinType && !in_array ($joinType, $allowedTypes))
        die ('Wrong JOIN type: '.$joinType);

    $this->_join[$joinType . " JOIN " . self::$_prefix . $joinTable] = $joinCondition;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * This method allows you to specify multiple (method chaining optional) ORDER BY statements for SQL queries.
 *
 * @uses $MySqliDb->orderBy('id', 'desc')->orderBy('name', 'desc');
 *
 * @param string $orderByField The name of the database field.
 * @param string $orderByDirection Order direction.
 *
 * @return MysqliDb
 */
public function orderBy($orderByField, $orderbyDirection = "DESC")
{
    $allowedDirection = Array ("ASC", "DESC");
    $orderbyDirection = strtoupper (trim ($orderbyDirection));
    $orderByField = preg_replace ("/[^-a-z0-9\.\(\),_]+/i",'', $orderByField);

    if (empty($orderbyDirection) || !in_array ($orderbyDirection, $allowedDirection))
        die ('Wrong order direction: '.$orderbyDirection);

    $this->_orderBy[$orderByField] = $orderbyDirection;
    return $this;
} 

/**
 * This method allows you to specify multiple (method chaining optional) GROUP BY statements for SQL queries.
 *
 * @uses $MySqliDb->groupBy('name');
 *
 * @param string $groupByField The name of the database field.
 *
 * @return MysqliDb
 */
public function groupBy($groupByField)
{
    $groupByField = preg_replace ("/[^-a-z0-9\.\(\),_]+/i",'', $groupByField);

    $this->_groupBy[] = $groupByField;
    return $this;
} 

/**
 * This methods returns the ID of the last inserted item
 *
 * @return integer The last inserted item ID.
 */
public function getInsertId()
{
    return $this->_mysqli->insert_id;
}

/**
 * Escape harmful characters which might affect a query.
 *
 * @param string $str The string to escape.
 *
 * @return string The escaped string.
 */
public function escape($str)
{
    return $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($str);
}

/**
 * Method to call mysqli->ping() to keep unused connections open on
 * long-running scripts, or to reconnect timed out connections (if php.ini has
 * global mysqli.reconnect set to true). Can't do this directly using object
 * since _mysqli is protected.
 *
 * @return bool True if connection is up
 */
public function ping() {
    return $this->_mysqli->ping();
}

/**
 * This method is needed for prepared statements. They require
 * the data type of the field to be bound with "i" s", etc.
 * This function takes the input, determines what type it is,
 * and then updates the param_type.
 *
 * @param mixed $item Input to determine the type.
 *
 * @return string The joined parameter types.
 */
protected function _determineType($item)
{
    switch (gettype($item)) {
        case 'NULL':
        case 'string':
            return 's';
            break;

        case 'boolean':
        case 'integer':
            return 'i';
            break;

        case 'blob':
            return 'b';
            break;

        case 'double':
            return 'd';
            break;
    }
    return '';
}

/**
 * Helper function to add variables into bind parameters array
 *
 * @param string Variable value
 */
protected function _bindParam($value) {
    $this->_bindParams[0] .= $this->_determineType ($value);
    array_push ($this->_bindParams, $value);
}

/**
 * Helper function to add variables into bind parameters array in bulk
 *
 * @param Array Variable with values
 */
protected function _bindParams ($values) {
    foreach ($values as $value)
        $this->_bindParam ($value);
}

/**
 * Helper function to add variables into bind parameters array and will return
 * its SQL part of the query according to operator in ' $operator ?' or
 * ' $operator ($subquery) ' formats
 *
 * @param Array Variable with values
 */
protected function _buildPair ($operator, $value) {
    if (!is_object($value)) {
        $this->_bindParam ($value);
        return ' ' . $operator. ' ? ';
    }

    $subQuery = $value->getSubQuery ();
    $this->_bindParams ($subQuery['params']);

    return " " . $operator . " (" . $subQuery['query'] . ")";
}

/**
 * Abstraction method that will compile the WHERE statement,
 * any passed update data, and the desired rows.
 * It then builds the SQL query.
 *
 * @param int   $numRows   The number of rows total to return.
 * @param array $tableData Should contain an array of data for updating the database.
 *
 * @return mysqli_stmt Returns the $stmt object.
 */
protected function _buildQuery($numRows = null, $tableData = null)
{
    $this->_buildJoin();
    $this->_buildTableData ($tableData);
    $this->_buildWhere();
    $this->_buildGroupBy();
    $this->_buildOrderBy();
    $this->_buildLimit ($numRows);

    $this->_lastQuery = $this->replacePlaceHolders ($this->_query, $this->_bindParams);

    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    // Prepare query
    $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();

    // Bind parameters to statement if any
    if (count ($this->_bindParams) > 1)
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->refValues($this->_bindParams));

    return $stmt;
}

/**
 * This helper method takes care of prepared statements' "bind_result method
 * , when the number of variables to pass is unknown.
 *
 * @param mysqli_stmt $stmt Equal to the prepared statement object.
 *
 * @return array The results of the SQL fetch.
 */
protected function _dynamicBindResults(mysqli_stmt $stmt)
{
    $parameters = array();
    $results = array();

    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    // if $meta is false yet sqlstate is true, there's no sql error but the query is
    // most likely an update/insert/delete which doesn't produce any results
    if(!$meta && $stmt->sqlstate) { 
        return array();
    }

    $row = array();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $row[$field->name] = null;
        $parameters[] = & $row[$field->name];
    }

    // avoid out of memory bug in php 5.2 and 5.3
    // https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/pull/119
    if (version_compare (phpversion(), '5.4', '<'))
         $stmt->store_result();

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $x = array();
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $this->count++;
        array_push($results, $x);
    }

    return $results;
}


/**
 * Abstraction method that will build an JOIN part of the query
 */
protected function _buildJoin () {
    if (empty ($this->_join))
        return;

    foreach ($this->_join as $prop => $value)
        $this->_query .= " " . $prop . " on " . $value;
}

/**
 * Abstraction method that will build an INSERT or UPDATE part of the query
 */
protected function _buildTableData ($tableData) {
    if (!is_array ($tableData))
        return;

    $isInsert = strpos ($this->_query, 'INSERT');
    $isUpdate = strpos ($this->_query, 'UPDATE');

    if ($isInsert !== false) {
        $this->_query .= '(`' . implode(array_keys($tableData), '`, `') . '`)';
        $this->_query .= ' VALUES(';
    }

    foreach ($tableData as $column => $value) {
        if ($isUpdate !== false)
            $this->_query .= "`" . $column . "` = ";

        // Subquery value
        if (is_object ($value)) {
            $this->_query .= $this->_buildPair ("", $value) . ", ";
            continue;
        }

        // Simple value
        if (!is_array ($value)) {
            $this->_bindParam ($value);
            $this->_query .= '?, ';
            continue;
        }

        // Function value
        $key = key ($value);
        $val = $value[$key];
        switch ($key) {
            case '[I]':
                $this->_query .= $column . $val . ", ";
                break;
            case '[F]':
                $this->_query .= $val[0] . ", ";
                if (!empty ($val[1]))
                    $this->_bindParams ($val[1]);
                break;
            case '[N]':
                if ($val == null)
                    $this->_query .= "!" . $column . ", ";
                else
                    $this->_query .= "!" . $val . ", ";
                break;
            default:
                die ("Wrong operation");
        }
    }
    $this->_query = rtrim($this->_query, ', ');
    if ($isInsert !== false)
        $this->_query .= ')';
}

/**
 * Abstraction method that will build the part of the WHERE conditions
 */
protected function _buildWhere () {
    if (empty ($this->_where))
        return;

    //Prepair the where portion of the query
    $this->_query .= ' WHERE ';

    // Remove first AND/OR concatenator
    $this->_where[0][0] = '';
    foreach ($this->_where as $cond) {
        list ($concat, $wValue, $wKey) = $cond;

        $this->_query .= " " . $concat ." " . $wKey;

        // Empty value (raw where condition in wKey)
        if ($wValue === null)
            continue;

        // Simple = comparison
        if (!is_array ($wValue))
            $wValue = Array ('=' => $wValue);

        $key = key ($wValue);
        $val = $wValue[$key];
        switch (strtolower ($key)) {
            case '0':
                $this->_bindParams ($wValue);
                break;
            case 'not in':
            case 'in':
                $comparison = ' ' . $key . ' (';
                if (is_object ($val)) {
                    $comparison .= $this->_buildPair ("", $val);
                } else {
                    foreach ($val as $v) {
                        $comparison .= ' ?,';
                        $this->_bindParam ($v);
                    }
                }
                $this->_query .= rtrim($comparison, ',').' ) ';
                break;
            case 'not between':
            case 'between':
                $this->_query .= " $key ? AND ? ";
                $this->_bindParams ($val);
                break;
            default:
                $this->_query .= $this->_buildPair ($key, $val);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Abstraction method that will build the GROUP BY part of the WHERE statement
 *
 */
protected function _buildGroupBy () {
    if (empty ($this->_groupBy))
        return;

    $this->_query .= " GROUP BY ";
    foreach ($this->_groupBy as $key => $value)
        $this->_query .= $value . ", ";

    $this->_query = rtrim($this->_query, ', ') . " ";
}

/**
 * Abstraction method that will build the LIMIT part of the WHERE statement
 *
 * @param int   $numRows   The number of rows total to return.
 */
protected function _buildOrderBy () {
    if (empty ($this->_orderBy))
        return;

    $this->_query .= " ORDER BY ";
    foreach ($this->_orderBy as $prop => $value)
        $this->_query .= $prop . " " . $value . ", ";

    $this->_query = rtrim ($this->_query, ', ') . " ";
}

/**
 * Abstraction method that will build the LIMIT part of the WHERE statement
 *
 * @param int   $numRows   The number of rows total to return.
 */
protected function _buildLimit ($numRows) {
    if (!isset ($numRows))
        return;

    if (is_array ($numRows))
        $this->_query .= ' LIMIT ' . (int)$numRows[0] . ', ' . (int)$numRows[1];
    else
        $this->_query .= ' LIMIT ' . (int)$numRows;
}

/**
 * Method attempts to prepare the SQL query
 * and throws an error if there was a problem.
 *
 * @return mysqli_stmt
 */
protected function _prepareQuery()
{
    if (!$stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare($this->_query)) {
        trigger_error("Problem preparing query ($this->_query) " . $this->_mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    return $stmt;
}

/**
 * Close connection
 */
public function __destruct()
{
    if (!$this->isSubQuery)
        return;
    if ($this->_mysqli)
        $this->_mysqli->close();
}

/**
 * @param array $arr
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function refValues($arr)
{
    //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(), '5.3') >= 0) {
        $refs = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $refs[$key] = & $arr[$key];
        }
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}

/**
 * Function to replace ? with variables from bind variable
 * @param string $str
 * @param Array $vals
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function replacePlaceHolders ($str, $vals) {
    $i = 1;
    $newStr = "";

    while ($pos = strpos ($str, "?")) {
        $val = $vals[$i++];
        if (is_object ($val))
            $val = '[object]';
        $newStr .= substr ($str, 0, $pos) . $val;
        $str = substr ($str, $pos + 1);
    }
    return $newStr;
}

/**
 * Method returns last executed query
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastQuery () {
    return $this->_lastQuery;
}

/**
 * Method returns mysql error
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastError () {
    return $this->_stmtError . " " . $this->_mysqli->error;
}

/**
 * Mostly internal method to get query and its params out of subquery object
 * after get() and getAll()
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function getSubQuery () {
    if (!$this->isSubQuery)
        return null;

    array_shift ($this->_bindParams);
    $val = Array ('query' => $this->_query,
                  'params' => $this->_bindParams
            );
    $this->reset();
    return $val;
}

/* Helper functions */
/**
 * Method returns generated interval function as a string
 *
 * @param string interval in the formats:
 *        "1", "-1d" or "- 1 day" -- For interval - 1 day
 *        Supported intervals [s]econd, [m]inute, [h]hour, [d]day, [M]onth, [Y]ear
 *        Default null;
 * @param string Initial date
 *
 * @return string
*/
public function interval ($diff, $func = "NOW()") {
    $types = Array ("s" => "second", "m" => "minute", "h" => "hour", "d" => "day", "M" => "month", "Y" => "year");
    $incr = '+';
    $items = '';
    $type = 'd';

    if ($diff && preg_match('/([+-]?) ?([0-9]+) ?([a-zA-Z]?)/',$diff, $matches)) {
        if (!empty ($matches[1])) $incr = $matches[1];
        if (!empty ($matches[2])) $items = $matches[2];
        if (!empty ($matches[3])) $type = $matches[3];
        if (!in_array($type, array_keys($types)))
            trigger_error ("invalid interval type in '{$diff}'");
        $func .= " ".$incr ." interval ". $items ." ".$types[$type] . " ";
    }
    return $func;

}
/**
 * Method returns generated interval function as an insert/update function
 *
 * @param string interval in the formats:
 *        "1", "-1d" or "- 1 day" -- For interval - 1 day
 *        Supported intervals [s]econd, [m]inute, [h]hour, [d]day,
```

Answer (score 0):

[M]onth, [Y]ear
     *        Default null;
     * @param string Initial date
     *
     * @return array
    */
    public function now ($diff = null, $func = "NOW()") {
        return Array ("[F]" => Array($this->interval($diff, $func)));
    }

```
/**
 * Method generates incremental function call
 * @param int increment amount. 1 by default
 */
public function inc($num = 1) {
    return Array ("[I]" => "+" . (int)$num);
}

/**
 * Method generates decrimental function call
 * @param int increment amount. 1 by default
 */
public function dec ($num = 1) {
    return Array ("[I]" => "-" . (int)$num);
}

/**
 * Method generates change boolean function call
 * @param string column name. null by default
 */
public function not ($col = null) {
    return Array ("[N]" => (string)$col);
}

/**
 * Method generates user defined function call
 * @param string user function body
 */
public function func ($expr, $bindParams = null) {
    return Array ("[F]" => Array($expr, $bindParams));
}

/**
 * Method creates new mysqlidb object for a subquery generation
 */
public static function subQuery()
{
    return new MysqliDb();
}

/**
 * Method returns a copy of a mysqlidb subquery object
 *
 * @param object new mysqlidb object
 */
public function copy ()
{
    return clone $this;
}

/**
 * Begin a transaction
 *
 * @uses mysqli->autocommit(false)
 * @uses register_shutdown_function(array($this, "_transaction_shutdown_check"))
 */
public function startTransaction () {
    $this->_mysqli->autocommit (false);
    $this->_transaction_in_progress = true;
    register_shutdown_function (array ($this, "_transaction_status_check"));
}

/**
 * Transaction commit
 *
 * @uses mysqli->commit();
 * @uses mysqli->autocommit(true);
 */
public function commit () {
    $this->_mysqli->commit ();
    $this->_transaction_in_progress = false;
    $this->_mysqli->autocommit (true);
}

/**
 * Transaction rollback function
 *
 * @uses mysqli->rollback();
 * @uses mysqli->autocommit(true);
 */
public function rollback () {
  $this->_mysqli->rollback ();
  $this->_transaction_in_progress = false;
  $this->_mysqli->autocommit (true);
}

/**
 * Shutdown handler to rollback uncommited operations in order to keep
 * atomic operations sane.
 *
 * @uses mysqli->rollback();
 */
public function _transaction_status_check () {
    if (!$this->_transaction_in_progress)
        return;
    $this->rollback ();
}
```

} // END class